# Which JTAG/SWD Programmer-Debugger do I need for rockchipRV1107?

Tags: arm, embedded, jtag, cortex-a, swd

I am trying to make a **SWD**-debug-session for the microprocessor **Rockchip RV1107**. This is a **ARM Cortex A7**. Unfortunately I don't know which programmer/debugger is able to connect to this microcontroller. Is it enough that the programmer/debugger support ARM Cortex A7 or should I look more specific for the RV1107 mC?
Could everybody give me some suggestions for a good programmer/debugger?

Some programmer/debugger which are maybe useful:

- http://www.embedded-projects.net/usbprog5/
- https://de.farnell.com/segger/8-08-93-j-link-edu-mini-classroom-pack/j-link-edu-mini-classroom-pack/dp/3106579
- very expensive!

Here is the Datasheet i found for the Rockchip RV1107
http://rockchip.fr/RV1107%20datasheet%20V1.1.pdf
On page 35 are the pins for SWD documented.

Thanks

Comment: adafruit has an FT232H breakout board that can be used with openocd to do jtag or swd as well as doing uart at the same time.   never heard of swd being used with a cortex-A but perhaps its possible.   can use one of these for jtag.  Some commercial packages will use/support ftdi, sometimes you have to change the product/vendor id to match their (overpriced) ftdi based programmer if it is ftdi based.  and a number of times you cant cut corners if you want to use pay-for software you have to buy the overpriced programmer.

Comment: its worth having this breakout in general, yes you may need to do some soldering, pretty easy and get some jumper wires (adafruit, sparkfun, ebay, amazon, etc).  cheap enough to gamble on in case it works before buying one of the higher priced ones.

Comment: if your I/O levels are not 3.3 but say 1.8 or 5.0 (unlikely) then you can get an FT2232H module from FTDI or mouser or digikey for around $20, they left VDDIO separate so that you can power it however you wish.

Comment: Pick one in your budget that is supported by your toolchain, and ideally comes with connectors/adaptors compatible with your board.  The question is entirely off-topic at SO, it is for you to decide using information you have not provided here in any case.

Comment: @old_timer According to the datasheet it _only_ supports SWD; although confusingly refers to the pins by their JTAG names TMS and TCK and erroneously refers to the port as "JTAG" rather SWDIO and SWCLK, but since it lacks TDI/TDO, I cannot see that it truly has JTAG support.  I may be missing something - but I doubt it.

Comment: sure, just a comment, swd can do the same things just fewer pins and more clock cycles.

Comment: The link you marked as "very expensive" is for a "classroom pack" if 12 devices! Even then the Farnell price is prohibitive Segger's US shop site sells it for $18. There are many alternatives, but if that is the extent of your search, and the care you have taken to understand what you are looking at, I dispair.